# Catching Exceptions error

Tags: php

So I first extract a single file from a ipa file(.plist file ) and then parse it with https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList.

Here is my php script:-

```
<?php 

error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'on' );

namespace CFPropertyList;
?>
```

I want to first try parsing binary string but it fails with error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CFPropertyList\PListException' with message 'Invalid binary string!' "

I tried:-

```
    catch(\PListException $e)
    catch("CFPropertyList\PListException" $e)
    catch(CFPropertyList\PListException $e)
```

but none of them works. Any workaround ?

Comment: You could be all-inclusive and catch (\Exception $e).

Comment: If you could put this as answer, I could approve this answer and +1 too.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt you can be all-inclusive and use `catch (\Exception $e)` instead.